# how do i keep css file at end of existing css using zend

Tags: zend-framework

```
NOTE : UPDATED MY QUESTION
```

Some times, we have to overwrite the css file in template page, by using following code

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/test.css');  ?>
```

This appends first file with all existing css file in our page.

For example,

```
<link href="/css/test.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/css.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/front.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

From Above source, `test.css` is appended.I need that be after `front.css`

it make new css file is overwritten by default css file.This results our new css is not reflecting in site. so we need to keep include the css file at end.
How can we include in zend? kindly advice on this.

Comment: What you describe is incorrect, the root of your problem must be somewhere else. Please give us more code.

Comment: @markus sorry i made mistake. Now i updated my question.kindly check

Comment: **note**: now it is a completely different question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prependStylesheet($href, $media, $conditionalStylesheet, $extras)` instead of append. Or even cleaner, use the helpers for all your stylesheets and append them in the right order.

Comment: when i use <?php $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/test.css');  ?> i am getting the same source

Comment: The you're doing something else wrong. Use append for ALL of your CSS files!

Comment: Thanks, i was put appendStylesheet in layout.html and prependStylesheet in my template page. thats why i did not get it.now i changed to prependStylesheet in both page.it works now